# How to change a set of characters between delimiters for exact line?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to write a script for changing user password in dovecot user database and I can't understand how to replace a set of characters between delimiters for exact lines with `sed`.

Please check this line for example (this is the part from dovecot userdb):

```
123@example.com:{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0vthg.LubtSCxRRK$MdTKNQ2Vk8ZW3XQXNXStt9rfr6fNa‌​XqPvZ0o9WJ8mW8y9ozE1pi8dYM8oQzwWa8ESGzEmJO6yT/tgi3ZEqAiE0:::
abc@example.com:{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0vthg.LubtSCxRRK$MdTKNQ2Vk8ZW3XQXNXStt9rfr6fNa‌​XqPvZ0o9WJ8mW8y9ozE1pi8dYM8oQzwWa8ESGzEmJO6yT/tgi3ZEqAiE0:::
```

How to replace the string between ":" delimeters starting with "{SHA512-CRYPT}" only for user "123@example.com" and not for user "abc@example.com" with sed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
sed 's/\(\(^\|:\)123@example\.com:\)\([^:]\+\)/\1foo/'
```

given there is no escaped delimiters in the value.

```
sed 's/\(\(^\|:\)123@example\.com:\)\([^:]\+\)/\1foo/'    
     |     |         |                |     | |  | |     
     |     |         |                |     | |  | +----- H. End of sub.
     |     |         |                |     | |  +------- G. Sub string
     |     |         |                |     | +---------- F. Match Group 1.
     |     |         |                |     +------------ E. End of Group 3.
     |     |         |                +------------------ D. Group 3.
     |     |         +----------------------------------- C. User
     |     +--------------------------------------------- B. Prefix Group 2.
     +--------------------------------------------------- A. Substitute
```

- `A:` `s/` Substitute command.
- `B:` `(^|:)` Starts with start of line or delimiter `:`, Group 2, part of match group 1.
- `C:` The user to match, part of match group 1.
- `D:` `([^:]+)` The part to remove, anything until `:`. Part of group 3. Everything until next delimiter. Should perhaps be `\(:\|$\)`, but as it should end in `:` it should suffice.
- `E:` `\)` Ending the removal grouping.
- `F:` `\1` Put back match group 1. User + delimiter(s).
- `G:` `foo` What ever is to be inserted as crypt.
- `H:` `/` Ending it all. Optioanlly an `/g` for global, but assume it is a once only.

Comment: Why you put this `\(\(` between substitution command and prefix group "B"? And thank you a lot - I ve tried this regex with `GNU sed version 4.2.1` - works like a charm!

Comment: @powerthrash: Because it is an either or expression. `(^|:)` -> Either ^ (start of line) | (or) : (colon). If no grouping  it would be `(^|:user@examp...)` as in: Either *Start of line* or *Colon followed by user ...*. In this case it would be best to omit it completely though, and use (^user@...), as also mentioned by mikeserv. You want to match start of line. http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile

Comment: @mikeserv: Yes, it replaces any `:password:` hash if present – not testing for [scheme](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes). Should not use `(^|:)` at start as it for one should be start and second I'm not sure if the user could be part of other (later) field (i.e. `:gecos:`).

Answer (score 7):

You can just alternate addresses here -

```
sed '/^123@example.com:{SHA512-CRYPT}/s/{[^:]*/REPLACE/'
```

Here the `s///`ubstitution command is a function of the `/regxp/` address and so the `s///`ubstitution is not even attempted unless the line first matches its parent address.

Or just w/ a single `s///`:

```
sed 's/^\(123@example.com:\){SHA512-CRYPT}[^:]*/\1REPLACE/'
```

Or by anchoring to the head-of-line only if 123 does not immediately follow a colon:

```
sed 's/^\(\(.*:\)*123@example.com:\){SHA512-CRYPT}[^:]*/\1REPLACE/'
```

While I am certainly no stranger to complicated sub-expressions, in this case such a thing is unnecessary - I usually prefer the address form when I can get it -  I find it easier to read, it is more efficient, and fully portable. Admittedly though, at a second glance it would seem I initially over-estimated the inherent complication here.

Similarly, you might also split the back-references and the actual substitution like:

```
sed -e '
/^\(123@example.com:\){SHA512-CRYPT}[^:]*/!b
s//\1REPLACE/
#other commands that can be sure to affect only a line matching the 1st address'
```

In the above example the address verifies a match by `b`ranching out of the script for any `!`not matching line, but it also pulls double-duty in saving the variable bit in `\1` for the next `s///`ubstitution should any line pass its match test. Moreover, all subsequent commands can also only be executed on a line which matches the initial address.

And of course there is the less-ultimate form which specifies a match function context with curly braces:

```
sed -e '
/^123@example.com:{SHA512-CRYPT}/{
    s/{[^:]*/REPLACE/
    #other function commands
};/other match function/{
    #still more commands...
}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F':' '/^123@example.com/ {$2="NEWPASSWORDHERE"}1' OFS=':' infile

123@example.com:NEWPASSWORDHERE:::
abc@example.com:{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0vthg.LubtSCxRRK$MdTKNQ2Vk8ZW3XQXNXStt9rfr6fNa‌​XqPvZ0o9WJ8mW8y9ozE1pi8dYM8oQzwWa8ESGzEmJO6yT/tgi3ZEqAiE0:::
```

- I used `awk` with its `-F` option to setting colon(`:`) as field separator and if line start(`^`) with `123@example.com` then replace column2(`$2`) with new value(`NEWPASSWODHERE`).
- `OFS=':'` Changes the output field separator from space(by default) to colon(`:`).
- The `1` on the end, enables printing by default.

Comment: One question - it's possible to modify a file with awk inplace like using sed with "-i" option?