# Removing contents from a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file like this

```
>gene1*ENSG24
CTTGGGGGGCTGGGGGCCAGGTGAAAGGGAAATGGAGGGCAGCACCCGCG
AGCCCTCATTGCCTATAGTGGTTTCCATGGCGATCATGTAAGAGTCAATG
TCGTCATTGGCAAAGTCGTCCGGGTGGGGTGTGCTGTAGGCAGAATCGGA
GTATCAGGGAGGGGACTGGGGGAGCAGAGGCAGGGCCCCACCTTGGAGGG
CTCGAAGGGAGCTCTGGGGCCCCCGACCACTGGAGA
>gene2*ENSG87
CCATTTTGAAACCCTTAATAAAAACTTGCTGGTCTGAGACTCAGCAGGCA
GCACAGACTTACTGATATGTACTGTCACCTCCAGCGGCCCAGCTGTAAAA
TTCCTCTCTTTGTAGTGTCTCTCTTTATTTCTCAGCTGGCTGACACTTAT
GGAAAATGGAAAGAACCTATGTTGAAATATTGGGGGCAGGTTCCATCAAT
AGTTCTTACATGG
```

I want output in the format below

```
>gene1
CTTGGGGGGCTGGGGGCCAGGTGAAAGGGAAATGGAGGGCAGCACCCGCG
AGCCCTCATTGCCTATAGTGGTTTCCATGGCGATCATGTAAGAGTCAATG
TCGTCATTGGCAAAGTCGTCCGGGTGGGGTGTGCTGTAGGCAGAATCGGA
GTATCAGGGAGGGGACTGGGGGAGCAGAGGCAGGGCCCCACCTTGGAGGG
CTCGAAGGGAGCTCTGGGGCCCCCGACCACTGGAGA
>gene2
CCATTTTGAAACCCTTAATAAAAACTTGCTGGTCTGAGACTCAGCAGGCA
GCACAGACTTACTGATATGTACTGTCACCTCCAGCGGCCCAGCTGTAAAA
TTCCTCTCTTTGTAGTGTCTCTCTTTATTTCTCAGCTGGCTGACACTTAT
GGAAAATGGAAAGAACCTATGTTGAAATATTGGGGGCAGGTTCCATCAAT
AGTTCTTACATGG
```

I want to remove the *ENSG part. How can I do that.

Comment: `sed '/^>gene[0-9]*\*/s/\*ENSG.*//' <infile >outfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be simple enough in `sed`:

```
sed 's/.ENSG[0-9]*$//'
```

Comment: this removes `[any character]ENSG[any numbers]` from *any* line ending with that pattern - which will work perfectly given the example data.

Comment: @mikeserv I considered using  `s/\(>.*\*\)ENSG[0-9]{2}$/\1/`, but decided to see if OP has any problems with this first.

Comment: That would work, too. In those cases though - when you need to verify a sequence before affecting another sequence - you should probably avoid `\(backrefs\)` though - they're less efficient than a simple address - *especially* when they contain `.*up-to-something` which is a somewhat costly computation for some regex engines, as opposed to `from something.*` which almost all handle efficiently. Look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170535/52934) for some examples on alternating addresses.

Comment: Thinking about it again - don't avoid the backrefs if figuring how to do so is going to cost you more time than it is worth - which is likely very little - I just thought I'd say that in case you didn't know - sometimes people don't consider it.

Comment: For the given example `sed 's/\*.*//'` is the shortest form and enough, I believe.

Comment: @mikeserv Fair enough. I don't mind altering habits to pick up better ones. The real question is, will the OP do so? I have seen enough questions involving nucleic acids to doubt it. :(

Comment: Some do, I think - @terdon is - as I think - a professional in the field *(if that's what bioinformatics means)* - and is pretty damn good at this stuff. Still, maybe we shouldn't fault them - while better scripting habits would be appreciated, I'd rather they focused on cancer cures or whatever - the world probably needs those more.

Comment: @jimmij - do you need to quote the star? I think there - at the head of the address - it is literal, right? I'm gonna look it up - that's interesting...

Comment: @mikeserv it matches the empty string in some cases (in perl, at least).

Comment: @jimmij - Maybe in `perl` - but in a [`POSIX BRE`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) *The \*asterisk shall be special except when used:
1. In a bracket expression

2. As the first character of an entire BRE (after an initial '^', if any)*

Comment: @mikeserv Ah , I was wrong. In perl you get this: `Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE a/ at -e line 1.`. An error straightaway.

Comment: @mikeserv that's interesting. I've probably never used unquoted `*` to match literal `*` at the beginning of the regexp.

Comment: @jimmij - ditto. I might default to quoting it, too. I only thought about it all as a result of your edit.

Comment: @jimmij - in fact I did, I guess. see the comment on the question here?